# How best to read multiple csvs into a single dataframe when each csv has multiple common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files in a directory. All these files have two columns which are common.

```
file1.csv
common_col1    common_col2    var1    var2    var3
 abc|xyz        2018-10-07     100     200     300
 abc|xyz        2018-10-14     80      80      90
 abc|xyz        2018-10-21     34      35      36
 abc|qrs        2018-10-07     1000    2000    3000
 abc|qrs        2018-10-14     800     800     90
 abc|qrs        2018-10-21     340     350     36  


file2.csv
common_col1    common_col2    var4    var5    var6
 abc|xyz        2018-10-07     "one"   150     203
 abc|xyz        2018-10-14     "two"   38      90
 abc|xyz        2018-10-21     "three" 35      45
 abc|qrs        2018-10-07     "four"  654     678
 abc|qrs        2018-10-14     "five"  67      90
 abc|qrs        2018-10-21     "six"   25      76
```

and likewise file3.csv, file4.csv etc.

Finally my result should look like:

```
common_col1    common_col2    var1    var2    var3   var4    var5 var6

 abc|xyz        2018-10-07     100     200     300   "one"   150     203
 abc|xyz        2018-10-14     80       80      90   "two"   38      90
 abc|xyz        2018-10-21     34       35      36   "three" 35      45
 abc|qrs        2018-10-07     1000    2000    3000  "four"  654     678
 abc|qrs        2018-10-14     800      800     90   "five"  67      90
 abc|qrs        2018-10-21     340      350     36   "six"   25      76
```

I tried the following code:

```
filepaths = [f for f in os.listdir("/home/csvfiles") if f.endswith('.csv')]
tmp_dump = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths), sort=False)
```

Though this is not duplicating 'common_col1' and 'common_col2' in tmp_dump, I am not sure this is the right thing to do. Indeed I am also seeing all NaNs for some columns which is bizarre! What is a good way for me to obtain a single dataframe?

Thanks for all and any help.
Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the common columns as an index

```
dir = '/home/csvfiles/'
filepaths = [dir + f for f in os.listdir(dir) if f.endswith('.csv')]

def read_csv(fp):
    return pd.read_csv(
        fp, delim_whitespace=True,
        index_col=['common_col1', 'common_col2']
    )

tmp_dump = pd.concat(map(read_csv, filepaths), sort=False, axis=1)
```

---

I'd prefer to use `pathlib` though

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

filepaths = Path('home/csvfiles/').glob('*.csv')

def read_csv(fp):
    return pd.read_csv(
        fp, delim_whitespace=True,
        index_col=['common_col1', 'common_col2']
    )

tmp_dump = pd.concat(map(read_csv, filepaths), sort=False, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely a beginner so will appreciate if you can help me understand why is the latter more preferred.

And I am getting an absolute bizarre result.  tmp_dump['common_col1'] is throwing a KeyError as is tmp_dump['common_col2'] but if I use tmp['var1'] it is printing me ---- 'common_col1   common_col2   and values of var1"

Comment: I like the `pathlib` library and the `Path` object because I fine the methods more elegant.  Use what you know.  Go read about the `pathlib` library and make your own choice.  I presented it as "I'd prefer..." to make it clear that it was my opinion and **not** a recommendation as best practice.

Comment: I am getting an absolute bizarre result. tmp_dump['common_col1'] is throwing a KeyError as is tmp_dump['common_col2'] but if I use tmp['var1'] it is printing me ---- 'common_col1 common_col2 and values of var1" Any "non common" variable I print, it is printing the values of common_col1 and common_col2 with it.

Comment: That is because `common_col1` and `common_col2` are a part of the index.  If you want it as you expected, use this instead `tmp_dump = pd.concat(map(read_csv, filepaths), sort=False, axis=1).reset_index()`